# What does the system put in buffer when you enter RETURN in keyboard

Tags: c++

It is well known that say if we use a loop of

```
cin.get(char_array, 10)
```

to read keyboard input. It will leave a 'delimiter'(corresponds to the 'ENTER' key) in the queue so the next iteration of cin.get(char_array, 10) will read the 'delimiter' and suddenly closed. We have to do this

```
cin.get(char_array, 10)
cin.get()
```

use an additional cin.get() to absorb the 'delimiter' so that we can input several lines in prompt in a row.

I really wonder here is, what exactly is the delimiter in the queue? Is it just '\0' which marks the end of a string? Say if I type "Hello" in prompt and push ENTER button, will the queue be like {'H','e','l','l','o','w','\0'}?

If the delimiter(corresponds to the ending "ENTER" key) is not '\0', will there be a '\0' automatically added to the end of the queue? say {'H','e','l','l','o','w','whatever_delimiter','\0'}

This question matters cause if we use a char* to store the input, we may consider extra places for those special marks. The actual chars you can store is fewer than you the seats you applied.

Comment: why don't you look at what `cin.get()` returns?

Comment: some nitpicking: You do not store a string in a `char*`, you store a string in an array of `char` and a `char*` can point to that. Confusing that leads to bugs.

Comment: Why are you using `cin.get()` and character arrays, rather than `std::getline` and `std::string`?

Comment: Also, there's not really a "queue" in the computer-science sense, but rather a *buffer*. Basically an array of characters. And the `Enter` key is added as a newline `'\n'` character in that buffer. There's no string terminator in the stream buffer, but `cin.get()` will put the string terminator into your array.

Comment: I am using cin.get() cause I am looking C++ primer plus and test all the methods mentioned from beginning. I know string class and getline are more common to use.

Comment: C++ Primer Plus by Stephen Prata [might not be the best book](https://accu.org/bookreviews/2002/glassborow_1744/).  [Here's a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) of good books.

Comment: Thanks sincerely for your help good sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'queue' associated with `std::cin` (it's normally known as a buffer) is the characters you type. This is true however you read from `std::cin`.

`get(array, count, delim)` reads until 1) end of file is reached, 2) `count - 1` characters have been read, or 3) the next character in the queue is `delim`. If not supplied `delim` defaults to `'\n'`.

So in your case the delim is `'\n'` and the read will continue until `'\n'` is the next character in the queue (assuming the read stops for reason 3 above).

A `'\0'` is added to `array` (assuming there is room) by the `get` function. It's never the case that `'\0'` is added to the queue.